# file URL on s3 to match files on website hosted elsewhere

Tags: url, amazon-s3, drupal

First I apologize if this is a duplicate because I've looked everywhere and the answers are either for slightly different scenarios or I just can't get them to work.

My scenario:
Hosting a Drupal site on a platform that does not support files larger than 250mb. Client wants a zip file that is 500mb to be hosted on the site and the reasoning is so that the url to the file is the same as any other file on the site. They want the ability to easily remove the file and replace it with a new large file in the future.

UPDATE:

1. I was successful masking an s3 file url with CNAME for a subdomain, but that will not resolve the issue that it is a slightly different URL and would require it's own ssl cert.
2. I'm using the s3fs module to set the default file location for the site to the s3 bucket. Now while setting up a file manager module, elfinder, I can't get it to know the new location to manage the files. Elfinder assumes they are in the local default files location. Once I've resolved this, I can tackle the cname.

Comment: What is the problem are you facing? Url does not work? Access denied or what error do you get. There are lot of ways that this can fail. More error messages will help to identify the problem.

Comment: When I go to add the CNAME record it says "could not add zone record" which I also felt was unhelpful. But then I googled it for the host and I learned when you create a subdomain, it automatically creates an A record which was causing the conflict! Now I can add the CNAME but the subdomain is not resolving to the s3 bucket file, instead I get a 404. Is there a certain way I should setup the subdomain?

Comment: Maybe you should change your way of solving this issue. first use different filesystem for drupal: [googl.com/#q=drupal+s3](http://googl.com/#q=drupal+s3) then use redirect for the s3 bucket with temporary access keys for downloading. the uploading will use streams(which is bit more difficult)

Comment: Thank you @JonnieJS! That's exactly the route I went but got stuck again. I've setup the s3fs module for the site files and I'm trying to get the file manager module elfinder to work with it. Currently elfinder still assumes the files are local and not on an s3 bucket :P

Comment: Hi @monnie, please make sure you have completely moved your filesystem to s3. technically all the URIs should change from `public://foo.txt` to `s3://foo.txt`. Please make sure to do everything the [README](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/s3fs/tree/README.txt?h=7.x-2.x) says.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, just a bit of code i cannot put inside the comment.

This code generates temporary link to download private files, that stored on S3 bucket.

Use it like this:

`$url = el_s3_getTemporaryLink('myaccesskey','mysecretkey','mybucket','linux.png', 1);// this link is alive for one minute.`

Which will output something like: `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?sometoken`

You can put that inside links like:
`l('Download now', $url, ['external'=>true]);`

```
<?php 

if(!function_exists('el_crypto_hmacSHA1')){
  /**
  * Calculate the HMAC SHA1 hash of a string.
  *
  * @param string $key The key to hash against
  * @param string $data The data to hash
  * @param int $blocksize Optional blocksize
  * @return string HMAC SHA1
  */
  function el_crypto_hmacSHA1($key, $data, $blocksize = 64) {
      if (strlen($key) > $blocksize) $key = pack('H*', sha1($key));
      $key = str_pad($key, $blocksize, chr(0x00));
      $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), $blocksize);
      $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), $blocksize);
      $hmac = pack( 'H*', sha1(
      ($key ^ $opad) . pack( 'H*', sha1(
        ($key ^ $ipad) . $data
      ))
    ));
      return base64_encode($hmac);
  }
}

if(!function_exists('el_s3_getTemporaryLink')){
  /**
  * Create temporary URLs to your protected Amazon S3 files.
  *
  * @param string $accessKey Your Amazon S3 access key
  * @param string $secretKey Your Amazon S3 secret key
  * @param string $bucket The bucket (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com)
  * @param string $path The target file path
  * @param int $expires In minutes
  * @return string Temporary Amazon S3 URL
  * @see http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/S3/20060301/s3-dg-20060301.pdf
  */

  function el_s3_getTemporaryLink($accessKey, $secretKey, $bucket, $path, $expires = 5) {
    // Calculate expiry time
    $expires = time() + intval(floatval($expires) * 60);
    // Fix the path; encode and sanitize
    $path = str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($path = ltrim($path, '/')));
    // Path for signature starts with the bucket
    $signpath = '/'. $bucket .'/'. $path;
    // S3 friendly string to sign
    $signsz = implode("\n", $pieces = array('GET', null, null, $expires, $signpath));
    // Calculate the hash
    $signature = el_crypto_hmacSHA1($secretKey, $signsz);
    // Glue the URL ...
    $url = sprintf('http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s', $bucket, $path);
    // ... to the query string ...
    $qs = http_build_query($pieces = array(
      'AWSAccessKeyId' => $accessKey,
      'Expires' => $expires,
      'Signature' => $signature,
    ));
    // ... and return the URL!
    return $url.'?'.$qs;
  }
}
```